# How would you go about building an interest graph based on the Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter, graph, ontology

Assume you have access to the Twitter firehose, either directly or through a Gnip/Datasift deal. You can analyze who users are following and the tweet streams. The end goal should be to have an ontology of interests, with weighted interests per user.

I am completely stuck even starting to work on this problem. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be along the lines of what you are looking for

http://wthashtag.com/

I'm pretty certain that Twitter has a category listing for lists, at least, in their own API as well.

GL

Comment: your welcome, btw you can accept answers if you find them satisfactory. fYI, I see your a new member :)